# Equal areas on squares of Bottema's theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

It is known from Bottema's theorem that if we have two squares with a common vertex, we can complete the formation as in the figure to make two other squares that also have a common vertex.

[image]

But I just discovered something additional: the sum of the areas of the first two squares is equal to the sum of the areas of the next two squares. In other words, we can write: $A+B=C+D$

I haven't proven it yet but I checked the equality on GeoGebra

My question is, is this feature already discovered?  If there are any references you can mention, please post them

I don't think it's too hard to prove but I haven't tried it yet, don't prove it please but any hints are helpful

Comment: Hint: (Ignore Bottema's theorem)Cosine rule is sufficient.